# How to get list of all cookies being created by a domain

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, cookies, plugins

I am trying to get list of all cookies of wordpress domain using a plugin.

On Page in front side I get the list of all cookies created by site.

But is there any possibilities to get all cookies list without run in front side and block them on page load and enable to load on button click.Like other site scanning cookie for a domain as other sites doing.

for eg:-

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ghostery-%E2%80%93-privacy-ad-blo/mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij?hl=en

https://www.cookiebot.com/en/

http://www.onlinecookieaudit.com/

It will be great if some one help.I have stuck on this more than 15 days.

```
            $ch = curl_init('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            // get headers too with this line
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIELIST, "ALL");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            // get cookie
            // multi-cookie variant contributed by @Combuster in comments
            preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $matches);

            $cookies = array();
            foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
                parse_str($item, $cookie);
                $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
            }
            var_dump($cookies);
```

I have tried using this above code but it does not return all the cookies created by site .It has a different list return to console as we see in cookies.

My purpose to make this kind of tool
http://www.cookie-checker.com/

Answer (score 1):

cURL wouldn't run javascript, so no, there won't be an approach to get those treats. You'll need to imitate or robotize a program so as to accomplish that. Luckily there are devices to encourage you. Possibly investigate PHP-webdriver